# axios method never gets called upon form submission in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a form that accepts a file to upload, but if I add the `type="submit"` attribute to my 'upload' button, the axios method in `handleSubmit` never gets called, however if I remove the `type="submit"` attribute and treat the button as a simple `onClick()` action, the axios method gets called normally. How should I resolve this problem? I'm also using react-bootstrap.
Edit: The button is attached to a form, I did not put up the code for simplicity

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);

    axios
      .post("some/path", data, {})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response = " + response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("failed response" + error.response);
      });
    console.log("file submitted");
  };
// code for a form, omiited for simplicity 
<Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit" variant="success" size="md">
Upload
 </Button>{" "}
```

Comment: If the button is not used within a form, you should not use type="submit". There is no "action" attribute on a form to fire. type="submit" is only for forms

Answer (score 1):

You choose one or the other.  Having `type=submit` is trying to find a form to submit for you but you already have a click handler. Again, you can handle it either way but since you already have a click handler, just keep it and get rid of the `type=submit`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might need to add onsubmit on the Form tag. The button , if present as an submit type fires onsubmit of the Form.